# Global array not storing values

Tags: c

I have the following file named `arr.c`..

```
unsigned long* arr[50];
unsigned long arrSizes[50];
unsigned short size = 0;

void add(unsigned long* x, int y){ 
  arr[size] = x;
  arrSizes[size] = y;
  size++;
}

void print() {
  int i,j;
  i=0;
  j=0;
  for(;i<size;i++){
     for(;j<arrSizes[i];j++)
        printf("%lu ",arr[i][j]);
     printf("\n");
  }
}
```

It prints an empty line, its not printing arr[2]. Any idea, why this might be happening?

Comment: Your code is highly obscure. What do you try to do?

Comment: @JohnB- are you the downvoter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `print` method `j` starts at 0, but it should be reset for each iteration of i.
Why not do it the normal way:

```
for(i = 0;i<size;i++){
 for(j = 0;j<arrSizes[i];j++)
```

Comment: @John3136 Are you sure that helps? `arrSizes` does not contain sizes of elements of whatever.

Comment: arrSizes is populated in the add method - there may be other problems I didn't spot, but this one stood out (to me)

Comment: I understand the code now!!!!! `arr`, `arr`, and `arr` are three different arrays, and `arr` contains the addresses of `arr` and `arr`.